# Change div css when user scrolls past it, using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

When a user scrolls past a div I need it's css changed to position:fixed.
Much like what is done here: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/ but with just plain jquery, without the plugin.
The div must also stop scrolling once the user scrolls to another div.
For example:

```
<div id="stuff"></div>
<div id="this"></div>//must start scrolling with user when user reaches it.
<div id="footer"></div>// when #this reaches within say, 10px, of #footer it must stop in it's current position, in order to prevent overlap
```

I'm assuming i'd use  `.scroll()` and `.css()`, but I have no idea where to go from there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I noticed in your answer `#this` disappears abruptly once you get down to `#footer`. I've tweaked your answer to allow for `#this` to stick to `#footer` and scroll which is a lot smoother.

My demo uses slightly different markup and is a little more verbose so jump over to jsFiddle and check it out.

### **Demo:** [jsfiddle.net/Marcel/e9hyw/](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/e9hyw/)

Comment: Please note, my demo uses the [throttle/debonce plugin](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-throttle-debounce/1.1/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js) which is recommended when the `scroll()` event is being utilised.

Answer (score 3):

This is what finally worked for me:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var topOfrel = jQuery("#this").offset().top;
    var topOffooter = jQuery("#footer").offset().top - jQuery(window).height(); 
    var topOffootero = topOffooter ;
    var boxheight = jQuery(window).height() - 130;//adjusting for position below
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        var topOfWindow = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        if (topOfrel < topOfWindow && topOffooter > topOfWindow) {
            jQuery("#this").css("position", "fixed").css("top", "130px").css("overflow","auto").css("height", boxheight + "px");

        } else {
            jQuery("#this").css("position", "static");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the page you reference uses jQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js">
```

and also has other Javascript included on it that we don't see

incidentally you can view it here:

```
http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/waypoints.js
http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/waypoints-sticky.js
```

the functions he uses can be seen there, but i would not say it's a quick answer. Based on his scripts he attaches a listener to the element after the page loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.my-sticky-element').waypoint('sticky');
    });
</script>
```

If you have specific questions ask away, but i doubt many will go through explaining the entire script for you.

Comment: I was looking for jquery only option, with no add-on.

Comment: The central difference here is that the code you are looking for will either be included inline as a large block, or saved in a separate javascript file (or addon) of your own. Technically his is not not an addon but just his code to perform what you're looking for.  You're looking for a listener on a Dom element that tracks current y position and if less than 0 on y set an absolute position.  again, the best answer I could give was to look at the functions in his "addon" and see if you can replicate just the part you want.