# How to get event when user at the end of div contend?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

can you please tell me how to get an event when user scroll it div contend at the end .I need to do some  task when user goes to end of div contend .Show one alert.It only show alert when user goes to the end of contend .

Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/prUYP/5/

```
<div data-role="page" id="test">
    <div id="test" class="left test_h" style="width:97%;">
        Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar AM (Listeni/səˈtʃɪn tɛnˈduːlkər/; born 24 April 1973)[1] is an Indian cricketer widely acknowledged as one of the greatest batsmen in One Day International cricket[2] In 2002, Wisden Cricketers' Almanack ranked him the second greatest Test batsman of all time, behind Don Bradman, and the second greatest one-day-international (ODI) batsman of all time, behind Viv Richards.[3] Tendulkar was a part of the 2011 Cricket World Cup winning Indian team in the later part of his career, his first such win in six World Cup appearances for India.[4] He was also the recipient of "Player of the Tournament" award of the 2003 Cricket World Cup held in South Africa. Tendulkar won the 2010 Sir Garfield Sobers Trophy for cricketer of the year at the ICC awards.[5] He has been recommended for the receipt of the Bharat Ratna award, in fact it has been speculated that the criteria for the award of the Bharat Ratna were changed to allow him receive the award.[6][7] He is also a member of Rajya Sabha of Parliament of India.[8] Tendulkar passed 30,000 runs in international cricket on 20 November 2009. On 5 December 2012, Tendulkar became first batsman in history to cross the 34,000 run aggregate in all formats of the game put together.[9][10][11] At 36 years and 306 days, he became the first ever player to score a double-century in the history of ODIs. Two years later he became the first player to score 100 international centuries. As of June 2013, Tendulkar has played 662 matches in international cricket.[12] Tendulkar has been honoured with the Padma Vibhushan award, India's second highest civilian award, and the Rajiv Gandhi Khel Ratna award, India's highest sporting honour. He was also the first sportsperson and the first one without aviation background to be awarded the honorary rank of Group Captain by the Indian Air Force. Tendulkar has received honorary doctorates from University of Mysore and Rajiv Gandhi University of Health Sciences.[13][14] Sachin holds the 19th rank in ICC Player Rankings for Test batsmen as of 17 March 2013.[15] On 1 August 2012, Sachin Tendulkar was nominated for the ICC People's Choice award for the third time.[16] In 2012, he was nominated to Rajya Sabha, the upper house of the Parliament of India.Sachin tendulkar was ranked 78th richest sportsman in the world according to the Forbes' list of world's highest-paid athletes for the year 2012.[17] In June 2013 list, Forbes rankes Sachin at 51st position in highest paid athletes list, with his total earnings were estimated to be USD 22 million.[18][19][20] Sachin Tendulkar was named as an Honorary Member of the Order of Australia in 2012.[21] On 23 December 2012, Tendulkar announced his retirement from ODIs.[22][23][24][25] Tendulkar has already stated that he will not be playing T20 
        <span class="cursor" style="font-size:23px;">|</span>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change div css when user scrolls past it, using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128979/change-div-css-when-user-scrolls-past-it-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#realTimeContents').on('scroll', function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
        alert('Ends');
    }
});
```

Little changes in your HTML.

**IDs are unique** so change you HTML like below,

```
<div data-role="page" id="test">
    <div id="realTimeContents" class="left test_h" style="width:97%;">
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/prUYP/9/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).height() > $(window).height())
    {
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
          alert("The Bottom");
        }
    }
});
```

[code](http://jsfiddle.net/prUYP/6/)